# Convert Objective-C block to Swift closure

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

I want to convert block to closure, but I can't figure out how. I don't know what's the problem.

**Objective-C:**

```
// monthBlock type
typedef NSString *(^JTCalendarMonthBlock)(NSDate *date, JTCalendar *jt_calendar);

// Block
self.calendar.calendarAppearance.monthBlock = ^NSString *(NSDate *date, JTCalendar *jt_calendar){
    return @"";
};
```

**Swift:**

```
// Swift closure
self.calendar.calendarAppearance.monthBlock = {(date:NSDate, jt_calendar:JTCalendar) -> NSString in
    return "" as NSString
}
```

produces error:

> Error: Cannot assign a value of type '(NSDate, JTCalendar) -> NSString' to a value of type 'JTCalendarMonthBlock!'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your parameter types don't quite match up. You can either do:

```
self.calendar.calendarAppearance.monthBlock = { (date: NSDate!, jt_calendar: JTCalendar!) -> String! in
    return ""
}
```

Or, more simply:

```
calendar.calendarAppearance.monthBlock = { date, jt_calendar in
    return ""
}
```

---

I assume `JTCalendar` is not your own class. If it was, you might consider auditing it, adding [nullability annotations](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) to make it explicit whether these parameters could be `nil` or not. In the absence of those annotations, Swift has no way of knowing whether these are `nullable` or not, so it interprets these parameters as implicitly unwrapped optionals.